# Keep Pycharm open after opening it from windows Git bash terminal

Tags: git, pycharm

I just changed my Git bash.bashrc file with an alias to open Pycharm using Git Terminal on Windows with the following alias :

```
alias pycharm="C:/Program\ Files/JetBrains/PyCharm\ 2020.3.1/bin/pycharm64.exe"
```

Like this I can open & code into a folder with the git command

```
pycharm [my directory]
```

But I wonder how I can keep my Pycharm window opened while closing the Git window I used to open it in the first place.
Because if I close the Git window it close also PyCharm.

Thank's in advance for reading this, hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
nohup pycharm >/dev/null &
disown
```

Comment: Hello, should I put it in the bash.bashrc files ? If so, where I should put it in the files  and how ? (or append it to my command in or to my alias)

Comment: Yeah you can, example with gitk:
alias gitk='nohup gitk > /dev/null & disown'

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** by Le Ngoc Thuong, thank's !!

So I changed my aliases in the bash.bashrc file with the following lines and it worked :

```
alias pycharm="C:/Program\ Files/JetBrains/PyCharm\ 2020.3.1/bin/pycharm64.exe  > /dev/null & disown"
alias webstorm="C:/Program\ Files/JetBrains/WebStorm\ 2020.3/bin/webstorm64.exe > /dev/null & disown"
```